# Figure* span two columns only on new page for Bioinformatics Journal Template

Tags: floats, two-column, templates

I am using the Bioinformatics template from https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fb87a233621a613683ec81

Unfortunately, it is not possible to insert a spanning figure with the `figure*` environment on the first page such that the image is at the bottom. It always appears at the second, new page on top. I have googled a lot and the suggestion to use package `dblfloatfix` does not compile because the document class `already defined c@dblbotnumber`.

The template uses a large document class file and styles, so I can not paste a simple code here. It would be great if someone could have a look at it and find a solution.

Comment: if the class has defined c@dblbotnumber presumably it has defined  double column bottom floats, what does it do if you use \begin{figure*}[b]....

Comment: It has no effect, I tried all combinations of h,b,t,! with now effect, the figure stays on top of page 2, although page 1 has lots of unused space.

Comment: Perhaps the journal style is supposed to exclude the possibility of placing these figures at the bottom?

Comment: Is there any news here?